# Having a script affect only a particular <div> or section in a particular page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, elementor

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var delay = 100; setTimeout(function() {
$('.elementor-tab-title').removeClass('elementor-active');
 $('.elementor-tab-content').css('display', 'none'); }, delay);
});
</script>
```

I'm using the above script to have the first item of Elementor's accordion closed by default. This affects all the accordions on the page (as it should).

How can we make it affect only a particular section of the page? (say css-class: xyz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using the parent element's specific class as part of your jQuery selectors.

```
....
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.xyz .elementor-tab-title').removeClass('elementor-active');
  $('.xyz .elementor-tab-content').css('display', 'none');
}, delay);
....
```